# mrimg backup files restore in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup

I have a file of Windows XP backup xpbackup.mrimg.

Can I restore this to Windows 7 PC and see the contents of backup without using Windows XP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.mrimg files are Macrium images. Those you can restore with the Macrium WinPE CD. If you do not have one, you can download the WinPE .iso **[from my OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%211812)**. Burn this to CD and boot your PC with this CD. Here is an article that explains how to restore a Macrium image:

http://kb.macrium.com/knowledgebasearticle50079.aspx

And here is **[a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rkSX5OzI-TA)** that my friend Keith (Kado) made that also explains the restore process.

If you want to just look at the content of that image or copy some files out of it, you can mount that in any system that has Macrium installed. Just double click on the mrimg file.The mounted volume will show in Computer where you can open it with a double click.

If you do not have a Macrium on the system, you have to look for a Version 5 edition (version 6 is paid only). Here is **[a CNET site](http://download.cnet.com/Macrium-Reflect-Free/3000-2242_4-10845728.html?part=dl-&subj=dl&tag=button)** that offers it. But be extra careful with the download because CNET has the habit of attaching PUPs and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation and links which you have provided. In the second last paragraph of your answer it is mentioned about mount in any system that has Macrium installed. Thus does this mean I need to first burn the image to a CD and then mount?

Comment: No, No - you have to install Macrium on that PC. That iso you have to get either from that CNET link I posted or find another download link. This link here would be another option ==> http://filehippo.com/download_macrium_reflect/ The iso from my OneDrive you would only need if you wanted to burn a recovery WinPE CD.